# Shipping Python modules in pyspark to other nodes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I ship C compiled modules (for example, python-Levenshtein) to each node in a [Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark) cluster?

I know that I can ship Python files in Spark using a standalone Python script (example code below):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name", pyFiles=['MyFile.py', 'MyOtherFile.py'])
```

But in situations where there is no '.py', how do I ship the module?

Comment: Related to [Easiest way to install Python dependencies on Spark executor nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495435/easiest-way-to-install-python-dependencies-on-spark-executor-nodes)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you can package your module into a `.egg` or `.zip` file, you should be able to list it in `pyFiles` when constructing your SparkContext (or you can add it later through [sc.addPyFile](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile)).

For Python libraries that use setuptools, you can run `python setup.py bdist_egg` to build an egg distribution.

Another option is to install the library cluster-wide, either by using pip/easy_install on each machine or by sharing a Python installation over a cluster-wide filesystem (like NFS).

Comment: This worked! I was able to create the egg file for the module using your command above, and then the process was as simple as adding the egg file in the pyFiles parameter. Cool stuff!

Comment: Any suggestions in getting PySpark to install .egg dependencies? Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119225/databricks-spark-egg-dependencies-not-installed-automatically

Comment: if my *.egg file depends on other 3rd party libraries, will this work as well?

Comment: @mgoldwasser how to do it in pyspark 2.0?

Comment: could you let me know how can we ship the .egg_info directory ? Is it the same ?

Comment: @Josh_Rosen yes, what is the egg_info directory for?

Answer (score 4):

There are two main options here:

- [If it's a single file or a `.zip`/`.egg`, pass it to `SparkContext.addPyFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686708/648265).
- [Insert `pip install` into a bootstrap code for the cluster's machines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39360646/648265).

  - [Some cloud platforms (DataBricks in this case) have UI to make this easier](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/680/how-to-install-python-package-on-spark-cluster.html).

People also suggest [using `python shell` to test if the module is present on the cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734072/spark-submit-fails-to-detect-the-installed-modulus-in-pip).