# spark-submit fails to detect the installed modulus in pip

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pip, pyspark

I have a python code which have the following 3rd party dependencies:

```
import boto3
from warcio.archiveiterator import ArchiveIterator
from warcio.recordloader import ArchiveLoadFailed
import requests
import botocore
from requests_file import FileAdapter
....
```

I have installed the dependencies using **pip**, and made sure that it was correctly installed by having the command **pip list**. Then, when I tried to submit the job to spark, I received the following errors:

```
ImportError: No module named 'boto3'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The problem of *no module named* not only happens with 'boto3' but also with other modules.

---

I tried the **following things**:

1. [Added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217090/how-to-get-python-libraries-in-pyspark) SparkContext.addPyFile(".zip files")
2. Using submit-spark **--py-files**
3. Reinstall pip
4. Made sure the [path env variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205264/how-do-i-install-pyspark-for-use-in-standalone-scripts) `export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH` and installed pip install py4j
5. Used python instead of spark-submit

Software information:

- Python version: 3.4.3
- Spark version: 2.2.0
- Running on EMR-AWS: Linux    version 2017.09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing `spark-submit` try going to `python shell` and try importing the modules. 
Also check which `python shell` (check python path) is opening up by default.

If you are able to successfully import these modules in python shell (same python version as you trying to use in `spark-submit`), please check following:

In which mode are you submitting the application? try `standalone` or if on yarn try `client` mode. 
Also try adding `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=(your python path)`

Answer (score 3):

All checks mentioned above worked ok but setting PYSPARK_PYTHON solved the issue for me.