# pyspark addPyFile to add zip of .py files, but module still not found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using `addPyFiles()` seems to not be adding desiered files to spark job nodes (new to spark so may be missing some basic usage knowledge here).

Attempting to run a script using pyspark and was seeing errors that certain modules are not found for import. Never used spark before, but other posts (from package in question https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras/issues/36#issuecomment-378918484 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39779271/8236733) recommended zipping the module and adding to the spark job via `sparkContext.addPyFiles(mymodulefiles.zip)`, yet still getting error. The relevant code snippets being...

```or-tag-here
from distkeras.trainers import *
from distkeras.predictors import *
from distkeras.transformers import *
from distkeras.evaluators import *
from distkeras.utils import *
```

(where the package I'm importing here cann be found at https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras),

```or-tag-here
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.app.name", application_name)
conf.set("spark.master", master)  #master='yarn-client'
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", `num_cores`)
conf.set("spark.executor.instances", `num_executors`)
conf.set("spark.locality.wait", "0")
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");

if using_spark_2:
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    sc = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf) \
            .appName(application_name) \
            .getOrCreate()
    sc.sparkContext.addPyFile("/home/me/Downloads/distkeras.zip") # see https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras/issues/36#issuecomment-378918484 and https://forums.databricks.com/answers/10207/view.html
    print sc.version
```

(distkeras.zip being a zipped file of this dir.: https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras/tree/master/distkeras), and

```or-tag-here
transformer = OneHotTransformer(output_dim=nb_classes, input_col="label_index", output_col="label")
dataset = transformer.transform(dataset)

"""throwing error...
.....
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 458, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named distkeras.utils

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
.....
"""
```

From the docs and examples I could find (http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile and https://forums.databricks.com/questions/10193/the-proper-way-to-add-in-dependency-py-files.html), the code above seems like it should work to me (again, never used spark before). Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Any more info that could be posted that would be useful for debugging?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Fixed problem. Admittedly, solution is not totally spark-related, but leaving question posted for the sake of others who may have similar problem, since the given error message did not make my mistake totally clear from the start.

**TLDR**: Make sure the package contents (so they should include an __init.py__ in each dir.) of the zip file being loaded in are structured and named the way your code expects.

---

The package I was trying to load into the spark context via zip was of the form

```
mypkg
    file1.py
    file2.py
    subpkg1
        file11.py
    subpkg2
        file21.py
```

my zip when running `less mypkg.zip`, showed

`file1.py file2.py subpkg1 subpkg2`

So two things were wrong here.

1. Was not zipping the toplevel dir. that was the main package that the coded was expecting to work with
2. Was not zipping the lower level dirs.

Solved with
`zip -r mypkg.zip mypkg`

More specifically, had to make 2 zip files

1. for the dist-keras package:

   `cd dist-keras; zip -r distkeras.zip distkeras`

see https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras/tree/master/distkeras

2. for the keras package used by distkeras (which is not installed across the cluster):

   `cd keras; zip -r keras.zip keras`

see https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras

So declaring the spark session looked like

```py
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.app.name", application_name)
conf.set("spark.master", master)  #master='yarn-client'
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", `num_cores`)
conf.set("spark.executor.instances", `num_executors`)
conf.set("spark.locality.wait", "0")
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");

# Check if the user is running Spark 2.0 +
if using_spark_2:
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    sc = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf) \
            .appName(application_name) \
            .getOrCreate()
    sc.sparkContext.addPyFile("/home/me/projects/keras-projects/exploring-keras/keras-dist_test/dist-keras/distkeras.zip")
    sc.sparkContext.addPyFile("/home/me/projects/keras-projects/exploring-keras/keras-dist_test/keras/keras.zip")
    print sc.version
```

Comment: Just want to hightlight **so they should include an __init.py__ in each dir.**.  This was the critical piece of the puzzle for me, and something that my local Python testing had been happy to not have.

Comment: I get a module not found error for some dependencies. Can you help me with passing the depedncies in a zip corretly.?

Answer (score 6):

if your module is as below

myModule \n

   - **init**.py

   -spark1.py

   -spark2.py

Don't go inside myModule folder and add to zip. This error you mentioned.

Instead, go outside the myModule folder.
right-click and add myModule folder to zip and give another name.

The idea is when spark extract your zip, there should be myModule folder exist with same name and hyrarchy

Comment: The "giving another name" part turned out to be significant. It didn't work for me otherwise.