# How to import a django rest framework api in a pyspark udf executor?

Tags: python, django, apache-spark, pyspark, django-rest-framework

I have a project where i'm integrating django rest framework (drf) and apache spark, so I have some endpoints and I need to execute some jobs with spark by using udf. I have the below structure of the project:

```
core/
    udf/
    ├── pyspark_udf.py
    ├── (and the rest of the files of a django app)
    api/
    ├── api.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── (and the rest of the files of a django app)
    udf.zip
```

So according with that structure:

1. First, in `api.py` file i have the endpoint where I need to execute the job.
2. Second, inside the `pyspark_udf.py`, I call to an endpoint that is in the `api.py` file, I do some logic there and return the response.
3. Then, again in the `api.py` file, I use the value returned to create a new column in a pyspark dataframe.
4. Finally, I return the json data response in the drf endpoint.

I achieved that behavior but using `requests` in the `pyspark_udf.py` function, which I considerer that is not elegant or best practice, working with an api that is in my own project, instead of do a simple call to the class of the drf endpoint.

I created the minimum code below to reproduce the error and If someone can find a solution, I will appreciate it:

`api/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import (ClassFooViewSet,ClassBarViewSet)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/foo/endpointExampleA', ClassFooViewSet.as_view({'post':'endpointExampleA'}), name='endpointExampleA'),
    url(r'^api/bar/endpointExampleB', ClassBarViewSet.as_view({'get':'endpointExampleB'}), name='endpointExampleB')
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

`api/api.py`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from udf.pyspark_udf import UdfExample

class ClassFooViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def __init__(self):
        self.response_data = {'error': [], 'data': []}
        self.data = {}
        self.code = 0

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def endpointExampleA(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # I also tried to import here the udf
        # from udf.pyspark_udf import UdfExample

        try:

            sc=SparkSession \
                .builder \
                .master("spark://192.168.0.105:7077") \
                .appName('word_cloud') \
                .config("spark.executor.memory", '2g') \
                .config('spark.executor.cores', '2') \
                .config('spark.cores.max', '2') \
                .config("spark.driver.memory",'2g') \
                .getOrCreate()

            sc.sparkContext.addPyFile("core/udf.zip")

            schema = StructType([
                StructField("id", IntegerType(),True),
                StructField("user", StringType(),True),    
                StructField("text", StringType(),True),
            ])

            df = sc.createDataFrame([(1,"user1",""), (2,"user2",""), (3,"user3","")], schema)

            text_udf = udf(UdfExample().msj, StringType())

            text_df = df.withColumn("text",text_udf(df["text"]))

            text_df.show(text_df.count(),False) # Here, I receive the error
            import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

            text_df = text_df.select('id','user','text').toJSON().collect()

            for elem in text_df:                    
                self.response_data['data'].append(json.loads(elem))

            sc.stop()
            self.code = status.HTTP_200_OK

        except Exception as e:
            self.code = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        return Response(self.response_data,status=self.code)

class ClassBarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self):
        self.response_data = {'error': [], 'data': []}
        self.data = {}

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def endpointExampleB(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.response_data['data'].append({"msj":"Hello World"})
        return Response(self.response_data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`udf/pyspark_udf.py`

```
# from api.api import ClassBarViewSet # This line fails

class UdfExample():

    def __init__(self):
        self.response_data = {'error': [], 'data': []}
        self.data = {}

    def msj(self, tweet):
        import json
        import requests 
        # from api.api import ClassBarViewSet   # This line also fails here

        try:

            # This works
            response = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/api/bar/endpointExampleB")
            response = response.content.decode('utf-8')
            json_response = json.loads(response)
            return json_response['data']

            # But I'd like to use this code, I can't import
            # api.api so this part doesn't works
            classB = ClassBarViewSet()
            classB.endpointExampleB(request)
            self.response_data = classB.response_data['data']

        except Exception as e:
            self.response_data['error'].append(str(e))
        return self.response_data
```

The error that I receive when try to do: `from api.api import ClassBarViewSet` is:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'ClassBarViewSet'`

**Things to know about the error and the code related:**

- First I created the udf folder with only the `pyspark_udf.py` file and an `__init.py__` file, but I was receiving `You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.` error, I tried with several of OS answers related, exporting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable, trying to execute the server with the `--settings=core.settings` parameter (I'm using only one `settings.py` file), but I couldn't find a solution, so I created a django app and then I fixed the error. Finally, I generated the udf folder with the `zip -r udf udf` command from top level, I mean the full udf folder.
- In the pyspark dataframe, I have another column that is generated by another pyspark udf, in that function I don't use any drf endpoint and works good.
- If I try to import a django Model like `from api.models import (User)` **inside of the msj() function** in the `pyspark_udf.py` file, then, I receive this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'`, that is [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450462/pyspark-addpyfile-to-add-zip-of-py-files-but-module-still-not-found/51508990#51508990) with the way of create the `.zip`. If I import the model at the top of the file, this error doesn't appear, I don't understand why.
- I have a frontend layer where I import the api and calls to the endpoints, without any problem, in the same way that I trying to import in the `pyspark_udf.py` file.

So why I cannot import the api in the pyspark udf app? I searched but I couldn't find another SO question related. Thanks in advance for any help!