# How to import matplotlib python library in pyspark using sc.addPyFile()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyspark, python-import, libraries

I am using `spark` on python both iteratively launching the command `pyspark` from Terminal and also launching an entire script with the command `spark-submit pythonFile.py`

I am using to analyze a local `csv` file, so no distributed computation is performed.

I would like to use the library `matplotlib` to plot columns of a dataframe. When importing matplotlib I get the error `ImportError: No module named matplotlib`. Then I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217090/how-do-i-get-python-libraries-in-pyspark) and tried the command `sc.addPyFile()` but you could not find any file relating to matplotlib that I can pass to it on my OS (OSX).

For this reason I created a virtual environment and installed matplotlib with it. Navigating through the virtual environment I saw there was no file such as `marplotlib.py` so I tried to pass it the entire folder `sc.addPyFile("venv//lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib")` but again no success.

I do not know which file I should include or how at this point and I ran out of ideas.

Is there a simple way to import `matplotlib` library inside spark (installing with virtualenv or referencing the OS installation)? And if so, which `*.py` files I should pass the command `sc.addPyFile()`

Again I am not interested in distributed computation: the python code will run only locally on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post what I have done. First of all I am working with `virtualenv`. So I created a new one with `virtualenv path`.

Then I activated it with `source path/bin/activate`.

I installed the packages I needed with `pip3 install packageName`.

After that I created a script in python that creates a zip archive of the libraries installed with virtualenv in the path `./path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`.

The code of this script is the following (it is zipping only `numpy`):

```
import zipfile
import os

#function to archive a single package
def ziplib(general_path, libName):

   libpath = os.path.dirname(general_path + libName)      # this should point to your packages directory 
   zippath = libName  + '.zip'      # some random filename in writable directory
   zf = zipfile.PyZipFile(zippath, mode='w')
   try:
       zf.debug = 3             # making it verbose, good for debugging 
       zf.writepy(libpath)
       return zippath           # return path to generated zip archive
   finally:
       zf.close()


general_path = './path//lib/python3.7/site-packages/'
matplotlib_name = 'matplotlib'
seaborn_name = 'seaborn'
numpy_name = 'numpy'
zip_path = ziplib(general_path, numpy_name)      # generate zip archive containing your lib                            
print(zip_path)
```

After that the archives must be referenced in the pyspark file `myPyspark.py`. You do this by calling the method `addPyFile()` of the `sparkContext` class. After that you just can import in your code as always. In my case I did the following:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.addPyFile("matplot.zip") #generate with testZip.py
sc.addPyFile("numpy.zip") #generate with testZip.py
import matplotlib
import numpy
```

When you are launching the script you have to reference the zip archives in the command with `--py-files`. For example:

```
sudo spark-submit --py-files matplot.zip --py-files numpy.zip myPyspark.py
```

I considered two archives because to me it was clear how to import one but not two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the matplotlib directory and pass it to `addPyFile()`. Or alternatively you can define a environment variable which includes user packages: `export PYTHONPATH="venv//lib/python3.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a py file with your code. Add pyfile to spark context.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.<your operations>
```

save the file as file.py. Add this to sparkcontext

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("file.py")
```