# How to cast timeUUID to timestamp in PySpark/Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timeuuid

I have a column named "occurance" which is a timeuuid in the string form. I want to to be converted/cast to timestamp. I tried couple of methods but couldn't get through it.

[image]

```
from uuid import *
import time_uuid

my_uuid = uuid.UUID(occurrence)
ts = time_uuid.TimeUUID(bytes=my_uuid.bytes).get_timestamp()
```

But gives this error below:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure `time-uuid` module is installed, e.g. by running `pip install time-uuid`?

Comment: An error was encountered:
invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install time uuid
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I am running this in EMR Notebook

Comment: I'm not at all a PySpark expert, but the error likely tells you don't have this module installed. **Take a backup** and try to find out a way to install the `time-uuid` module. This answer looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217090/how-do-i-get-python-libraries-in-pyspark

Comment: jupyter notebooks let you run shell commands using the `!` prefix in the cell. to install use `!pip install <module name>`