# Cannot send Python dependencies to Spark on EMR via Livy

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, livy

I searched and viewed a looot of articles online and finally found a possible solution in:

[I can't seem to get --py-files on Spark to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461054/i-cant-seem-to-get-py-files-on-spark-to-work)

I followed the most voted answer in that link but it is not working for me. And that topic is 3 years old and I think I should submit a new question.

So what I did is like in that answer:

1. Build my python dependencies into a .zip:

```
pip install -t dependencies -r requirements.txt
cd dependencies
zip -r ../dependencies.zip .
```

And then upload it with other python files to my s3 bucket.

2. In `my_job.py`, add the following line to add my python dependencies.zip to PYTHONPATH:

```py
sc.addPyFile("dependencies.zip")
```

Note that this line is added at the very beginning of my python code.

3. Submit my Spark job. Well, in the link it used spark-submit, in my case I use curl through Apache Livy after ssh to my AWS EMR master:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"file": "s3://my-bucket/src/my_job.py", "pyFiles": ["s3://my-bucket/src/global_settings.py", "s3://my-bucket/src/sys_init.py", "s3://my-bucket/src/dependencies.zip"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://ec2-1-23-456-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8998/batches
```

Now, from the log of Livy, I got a Java exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/dependencies.zip does not exist
```

The full error trace is like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/tmp/spark-bfbaa559-69b8-48cb-9287-c30f73ab6d4a/my_job.py", line 1, in <module>
    from global_settings import *
  File "/mnt/tmp/spark-bfbaa559-69b8-48cb-9287-c30f73ab6d4a/global_settings.py", line 28, in <module>
    sc.addFile('dependencies.zip')
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 898, in addFile
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.addFile.
: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/dependencies.zip does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:452)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1544)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Totally have no idea on why spark cannot find `dependencies.zip` while it can find out the other two python files `global_settings.py` and `sys_init.py`.

Also note that the `dependencies.zip` is 48 MB. Does the file size matter? I don't think it is a problem for AWS EMR to read a 48 MB file from AWS S3. They are in the same region and under the same VPC.

And my requirements.txt:

```
pandas
sqlalchemy
boto3
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files, zips, eggs mentioned as part of `pyFiles` in the curl call will set the spark config `spark.submit.pyFiles`. 
Spark takes cares of downloading the files and add adding the files/zips to `PYTHONPATH`.
Use don't need to add the file add the files again using `sc. addPyFile(<>)`.(The above code is trying to look for filename dependencies in the default FS which in your case is file:// and Spark is not able to find it).
We can remove the `addPyFile` call, and try to import a class in the zip file specified to confirm if its part of the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thanks, with this change Spark can find my pandas module in `dependencies.zip` now. But then pandas cannot find its own dependency 'numpy'. The error is:

```
        "  File \"/mnt/tmp/spark-a6cd7c80-abc6-46e0-8c7a-88e5ab8a63c6/userFiles-23e6ce24-f6c4-4e89-b857-799eacf4c208/dependencies.zip/pandas/__init__.py\", line 19, in <module>",
        "ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']"
```
I tried explicitly import numpy but it is not helping. Is there any way to fix this or it is a PySpark limitation to find hierarchical dependencies? Or I should open a new ticket?

Comment: I dont think it PySpark can automatically get the transitive dependencies like for Maven. We can 1. package `numpy`(and any other dependencies as part of the zip) 2. Install numpy in all nodes using pip

Comment: Thanks. I have tried package `numpy` in the `dependencies.zip` alongside `pandas` but it is still not working.