# How do I add a Python module from inside conda's site-package directory to spark-submit?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, fuzzywuzzy, spark-submit

I need to run a PySpark application (v1.6.3). There is the `--py-files` flag to add .zip, .egg, or .py files. If I had a Python package/module at `/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy`, how would I include this whole module?

Inside this directory, I do notice some *.py and *.pyc files.

- fuzz.py
- process.py
- StringMatcher.py
- string_processing.py
- utils.py

Would I have to include each of these one-by-one? For example.

```
spark-submit \
 --py-files /usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py,/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py,/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/StringMatcher.py,/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/string_processing.py,/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py
```

Is there an easier way?

- should I try to find the .egg or .zip and use it (e.g. [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy/0.15.0))?
- can I just zip up this directory and pass that in?

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated. In reality, there are more Python modules managed by conda that I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to install Python dependencies on Spark executor nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495435/easiest-way-to-install-python-dependencies-on-spark-executor-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it in other direction. Installing `pyspark` to Anaconda with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark=2.1.1
```

Comment: I don't think that will work (haven't tried it). But, just thinking about it, why would installing pyspark to conda environment help with installing a third party library being available to the cluster at run-time?

Comment: After installing pyspark to conda environment you will be able to use Spark together with other packages installed with Anaconda, including standard Anaconda packages and additionally installed packages.

Comment: Is `pyspark=2.1.1` for Spark `1.6.3`? Or shall I use `pyspark=1.6.3`.

Comment: If you need Spark 1.6.3 you should use pyspark=1.6.3