# Databricks (Spark): .egg dependencies not installed automatically?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dependencies, pyspark, egg

I have a locally created `.egg` package that depends on `boto==2.38.0.` I used setuptools to create the build distribution. Everything works in my own local environment, as it fetches `boto` correctly from `PiP`. However on `databricks` it does not automatically fetch dependencies when I attach a library to the cluster.

I really struggled now for a few days trying to install a dependency automatically when loaded on databricks, I use `setuptools;` `'install_requires=['boto==2.38.0']'` is the relevant field.

When I install `boto` directly from `PyPi` on the `databricks` server (so not relying on the `install_requires` field to work properly) and then call my own `.egg`, it does recognize that `boto` is a package, but it does not recognize any of its modules (since it is not imported on my own .egg's namespace???). So I cannot get my `.egg` to work. If this problem persists without having any solutions I'd think that is a really big problem for `databricks` users right now. There should be a solution of course...

Thank you!

Comment: Loek, did you ever determine a solution?

Comment: @JohnA.Ramey I have not, but I also haven't been working on this issue anymore. I remember that the databricks team told me that they're in the process of resolving this. I assume you're currently running into the same issues? Sorry to hear that. Let me know when you've found a solution yourself :)

Comment: any progress about this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

Your application's dependencies will not, in general, work properly if they are diverse and don't have uniform language support. The [Databrick docs](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/clusters/python3.html) explain that

> Databricks will install the correct version if the library supports both Python 2 and 3. If the library does not support Python 3 then library attachment will fail with an error.

In this case it will not automatically fetch dependencies when you attach a library to the cluster.