# How do I install my code and dependencies in an AWS Spark cluster?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pip

I can create a Spark cluster on AWS as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-launch.html).

However, my own Python code and pip libraries need to run on the master and workers. This is a *lot* of code, and the pip installation process compiles some native libraries as well, so I can't simply have Spark distribute this code at runtime using techniques such as [registering a pip requirements file with spark_context](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5929) or the [--py-files argument of spark-submit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html).

Of course I could run a bash script right after  running `aws emr create-cluster`, but I wonder if there is a  more automatic way, so that I can  avoid the maintenance of a big bash script for installation.

So, what is the best way to  set up clusters to include my code and dependencies?

Comment: you could write/run a json file to execute the bash script (to make it look automatic), I had a similar problem and have not found another way yet.

Comment: I believe this question is covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686474/shipping-python-modules-in-pyspark-to-other-nodes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shipping python modules in pyspark to other nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686474/shipping-python-modules-in-pyspark-to-other-nodes)