# Does spark-submit send zipped python scripts to all nodes in the cluster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am confused about the behavior of spark-submit and the online docs are not leading me to the answer.  Say I have a Python driver program that depends on some additional modules I have written. In order to work I have to zip those modules up and include the zipped file with my spark-submit command.  Do those modules get distributed to each node in the cluster?

Comment: My understanding is yes, they are copied to each node. Unfortunately, I cannot provide any documentation to back this up. I will add that you don't _have_ to zip the files, you can also specify `.py` files (I believe comma separated, but it could be space) in the `--py-files` argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shipping python modules in pyspark to other nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24686474/6910411)