# Importing custom modules to AWS EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a s3 repository containing a 'main.py' file, with custom modules that I built (inside 'Cache' and 'Helpers'):
[image]

My 'main.py' file looks like that:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from spark_main import spark_process
from Cache import redis_main

file_root = 'flexible_dates_emr\parquet_examples\pe_1.parquet'
city_pairs = [('TLV', 'NYC', 'NYC', 'TLV'), ('TLV', 'ROM', 'ROM', 'TLV')]

def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()
    spark_data = spark_process(spark, file_root, city_pairs)
    redis_main.redis_update_from_older_file(spark_data)
    print(spark_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have an EMR cluster with all the requirements of the project that's working well, but when I try to import a module such as 'spark_process' or 'redis_main' my task fails.

I guess the reason is because it doesn't recognize the files that the modules are in.

My task is:
[image]

How can I use the modules?
thanks.

Comment: just copy the folders to the cluster's hdfs and ship it to executors.

Comment: how do I ship it?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24686474/8279585)